# 24 bit counter state machine

Tags: verilog, fpga

I am trying to create a counter in verilog which counts how many clock cycles there have been and after ten million it will reset and start again.

I have created a twenty four bit adder module along with another module containing twenty four D Flip flops to store the count of the cycles outputted from the adder.

I then want to have a state machine which is in the count state until ten million cycles have passed then it goes to a reset state.

Does this sound right?  The problem is I am not sure how to implement the state machine.

Can anyone point me to a website/book which could help me with this?

thanks

Answer (score 4):

As Paul S already mentioned, there is no need for a state machine if you want your counter to keep counting after an overflow. You can do something like this (untested, might contain typos):

```
module overflow_counter (
  clk,
  reset,
  enable,
  ctr_out
);

// Port definitions
input clk, reset, enable;
output [23:0] ctr_out;

// Register definitions
reg [23:0] reg_ctr;

// Assignments
assign ctr_out = reg_ctr;

// Counter behaviour - Asynchronous active-high reset
initial reg_ctr <= 0;
always @ (posedge clk or posedge reset)
begin
  if (reset)                 reg_ctr <= 0;
  else if (enable)
  begin
    if (reg_ctr == 10000000) reg_ctr <= 0;
    else                     reg_ctr <= reg_ctr + 1;
  end
end

endmodule
```

Of course, normally you'd use parameters so you don't have to make a custom module every time you want an overflowing counter. I'll leave that to you ;).

*[Edit]* And here are some documents to help you with FSM. I just searched Google for "verilog state machine":

- [EECS150: Finite State Machines in Verilog](http://inst.eecs.berkeley.edu/~cs150/Documents/FSM.pdf)
- [Synthesizable Finite State Machine Design Techniques](http://www.sunburst-design.com/papers/CummingsSNUG2003SJ_SystemVerilogFSM.pdf)

I haven't read the first paper, so I can't comment on that. The 2nd one shows various styles of coding FSMs, among which the 3 always blocks style, which I highly recommend, because it's a lot easier to debug (state transitions and FSM output are neatly separated). The link seems to be down, so here is [the cached Google result](https://encrypted.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=CummingsSNUG2003SJ_SystemVerilogFSM.pdf&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CCAQxQEwAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fdocs.google.com%2Fviewer%3Fa%3Dv%26q%3Dcache%3A6lfny2xIixgJ%3Awww.sunburst-design.com%2Fpapers%2FCummingsSNUG2003SJ_SystemVerilogFSM.pdf%2B%26hl%3Den%26pid%3Dbl%26srcid%3DADGEEShfu8w3JC6vqjyefyNr5IHoKSL7A92Og1WEXvaJmb_4geRD50wWYM2Rv0WlAOHEjscKKF1sdl-CqGpXIAVGskpzuUvhTc6p3CYlENr3KA8E_L92HNIBQmByhhgoWq9axWgsn5PG%26sig%3DAHIEtbTJm3RjToTsx02_1iMo7qX1qgNmHA&ei=0ueqTpmLOsX68QOcnJy6Cw&usg=AFQjCNG65PIz8BCYijt0jUKIPUAIfCxJ3Q&sig2=PDFy0lDQCPq4cUnPs9Cj-Q).

Answer (score 3):

You don't need a state machine. You already have state in the counter. All you need to do is detect the value you want to wrap at and load 0 into your counter at that point

In pseudo-code:

```
if count == 10000000 then
  nextCount = 0;
else
  nextCount = count + 1;
```

...or...

```
nextCount  = count + 1;
if count == 10000000 then
  resetCount = 1;
```

Answer (score 2):

State machines are not too tricky. Use localparam (with a width, don't forget the width, not shown here because it is just one bit) to define labels for your states. Then create two reg variables (`state_reg`, `state_next`). The `_reg` variable is your actual register. The `_next` variable is a "wire reg" (a wire that can be assigned to inside a combinational always block). The two things to remember are to do `X_next = X_reg;` in the combinational always block (and then the rest of the combinational logic) and `X_reg <= X_next;` in the sequential always block. You can get fancy for special cases but if you stick to these simple rules then things should just work. I try not to use instantiation for very simple things like adders since Verilog has great support for adders.

Since I work with FPGAs, I assign initial values to my registers and I don't use a reset signal. I'm not sure but for ASIC design I think it is the opposite.

```
localparam STATE_RESET = 1'b0, STATE_COUNT = 1'b1;

reg [23:0] cntr_reg = 24'd0, cntr_next;
reg state_reg = STATE_COUNT, state_next;

always @* begin
    cntr_next = cntr_reg; // statement not required since we handle all cases
    if (cntr_reg == 24'd10_000_000)
        cntr_next = 24'd0;
    else
        cntr_next = cntr_reg + 24'd1;
    state_next = state_reg; // statement required since we don't handle all cases
    case (state_reg)
        STATE_COUNT: if (cntr_reg == 24'd10_000_000) state_next = STATE_RESET;
    endcase
end

always @(posedge clk) begin
    cntr_reg <= cntr_next;
    state_reg <= state_next;
end
```

I found [this book](http://books.google.com/books/about/FPGA_prototyping_by_Verilog_examples.html?id=OoOwAKnTv78C) to be very helpful. There is also a VHDL version of the book, so you can use both side-by-side as a Rosetta Stone to learn VHDL.

Comment: I fail to see what the state accomplishes in your example. Nothing depends on it. If that code where to be put in an FPGA, the synthesizer would optimize the state related code away.

Comment: I was answering the original question.